# update url with jquery show/hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

New to jquery. I'm trying to show/hide function with link, but its not working completely. is it loading problem? 
I need

```
<a href='127.0.0.1/example/1' class='show_hides1'>click me</a>
```

Not

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='show_hides1'>click me</a>
```

have any  Idea? Suppose, I stay in 127.0.0.1/example and I need to go 127.0.0.1/example/1 and steel need show/hide. both page has my hide content. how can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean? what exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: IOW, you want to update the URL to a shown/hidden version of the page when the user clicks that thing, but without actually reloading the page?

Comment: yea, I want this, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show/hide elements using jQuery, use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show_hides1").click(function() {
        $("<somethingtoshoworhide>").toggle();
    });
});
```

Also, remove the `href` entirely, or also add `return false;` to the end of your `click` function so that it does visit the specified `href` page.

Comment: Well said, I personally would create a CSS class with only display:hidden and then use jQuery toggleClass in the event handler.

Comment: Yeh, I'm kind of with you in that camp in all fairness, I love a good `.hidden` class over inline-styling :)